# How to troubleshoot events in the Windows Event Logs?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, windows-event-log

- **How do you troubleshoot events that are not clear when you read them?**
- **Is there a website to search for those Event IDs and errors?**

In the following example event it is clear that the gateway resolution fails for the network location awareness service, but it is not clear what the cause of this event is, nor what error code 0x43 stands for.

Looking for a solution on Google I end up with no results matching this event...
[Google Query: nlasvc 4205 0x43](http://www.google.be/search?q=nlasvc+4205+0x43)

> **Source:**
> Microsoft-Windows-NlaSvc
>
> **Event ID:**
> 4205
>
> **Task Category:**
> Gateway Resolution
>
> **Description:**
> Gateway resolution failed on interface
> {075d4968-2da9-4051-9a43-43da54e86ca5}
> for 192.168.1.1 with error: 0x43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the other part of your question:
The 0x43 in windows networking world means "The network name cannot be found" 0x43 = Decimal 67. So if you look up windows error code 67, you'll get this up.

I must say that this is one of those times when we'll have to sit and analyze the issue for a good time. I'd probably do the following in this case:

1. Examine the errors and establish a pattern(like are they occuring after a specific event, like during start up, shutdown, start up of an application, etc.) and then try to narrow down the list of possible culprits.
2. I will also try to isolate it further by checking if its specific to this user(have another user login to the same box), or specific to this machine(have this user login to another box).
3. Then use the tools to capture the invisible details: procmon, procexp, tcpview, windbg etc., until the event occurs again, and then look at the info. I usually find something here(success rate > 75%)
4. possibly something else based on the above three steps.

Of course, I'll keep using Google; hey it's an extension of our brains, no?

The ideal approach in the troubleshooting world has to be isolate-and-conquer. Hope I made some sense.

Comment: +1 - Thinking through the message, understanding what service programs do, and doing basic investigation yourself are the best ways to figure out what an error in a closed-source program means. Read the docs for the product, search the Internet, and understand how the software works. For Windows OS-related errors, I have a lot of good luck w/ searching for the error code (0x00000043) and "winerror.h" (the C "header" file w/ the OS error codes in it). You end up with pages like this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199(PROT.10).aspx) that can help a lot.

Comment: Seems the Windows errors are more commonly shared than I thought, indeed a good way to look at the right place or trying it in a decimal form. After a closer inspection of the event log: This is happening when I resume from standby, it indicates that it can't find the Router because the connection hasn't been re-established. I don't think I can troubleshoot this much so I might just ignore that log event. :-)

Comment: Found another good site while looking for another error: http://bug.gd/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any sites offering this info and wait to be corrected. However answering your in a general way is say - this is where your skills as fault finder come into play.

i'd start by searching for key words, NlaSvc for example. Then possibly identifying the interface - maybe going to search for other log messages. All in all its a hunt the thimble game and you'll get better at it as you do more.

PS. I'm not saying you haven't done this - but this is how I'd approach a problem like this.

Put it into google, put parts of it into google, find associated information and repeat.

Comment: Google doesn't work for me this time, and indeed, most of the time it does... See for example: http://www.google.be/search?q="Gateway+resolution+failed+on+interface" and looking for any combinations of the keywords I don't get a related answer for 0x43 either, even not 43 or 0x00000043.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, try http://eventid.net

They have comprehensive info about almost every error logged in the event viewer.

Comment: I stand corrected :-)

Comment: Indeed an useful site, lists a lot of the Event IDs that are appearing in my logs, still no information for NlaSvc.

Comment: I wholly disagree. EventID.net is *CRAP*. It's a bunch of speculating idiots who don't understand that correlation does not imply cause! "Oh, this event happened to me on a Tuesday. Therefore it must be caused by Tuesdays!" I'm sure there's some good information there, but it's mostly crap. It's like a dumber version of ExpertSexChange. (I'd be game for a free community "event ID" type site like Server Fault so that we could kill EventID.net's business... right after we put ExpertSexChange out of business.)

Comment: Indeed, although sometimes when you Google for a problem, Experts Exchange shows up and for the answers you have to scroll down to the end of the page (just a hotkey) and then you find a solution there. But I wouldn't ask something myself nor pay for their expertise.

Comment: @TomWij: Don't worry-- I have high hopes that Server Fault will decimate ExpertSexChange's business, and you won't have to "scroll down" anymore. *smile*